# Center contents in Bootstrap container-fluid div

Tags: bootstrap-4

In container-fluid I have content how to make that content to center by using any bootstrap class. I can use margin and padding, but I don't want to use that. Please help to achieve this.

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSuitcase } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container-fluid customcolor'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='icon'>
            <FontAwesomeIcon className='suitcasestyle fa-5x' icon={faSuitcase}></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </div>
          <div className='text'>
            <h1>Job Application</h1>
            <h3>Please complete the form below to apply for a position with us.</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is App.css

```
.customcolor {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to align text center, you need to add class `text-center` to `container-fluid` div.

If you need to align the contents inside, you need to add class `justify-content-center` to the corresponding row. Else you need have another div wrapper around you rows.

eg: `<div className="d-flex justify-content-center">...</div>`

`d-flex` is required.

Also `row` should have child elements with class `col` or `col-*`

I would write something like this.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='container-fluid customcolor text-center'>
  <div class='row justify-content-center'>
    <div class="col-auto">

      <div class='text'>
        <h1>Job</h1>
        <h3>Please comp.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content) for further information